# Getting the 1st value in a subset of data

Tags: linq, lambda

I have a result coming back from a LINQ statement that looks like this:

```
 Id dataId dataVal 
 A  1      1000 
 A  2      2000 
 A  3      3000 
 A  3      3001 
 A  3      3002
```

What I'd like is to just get the 1st item (dataId = 3 and dataVal = 3000)

Here is my query that is generating the above result:

```
        var myIds = myList
            .Where(a => ListIds.Contains(a.dataId))
            .Select(x=> new 
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                DataId = x.dataId,
                DataValue = x.DataValue
            }).ToList().Distinct();
```

Do I need to do some grouping or is there an easier way?

Comment: How is (dataVal - 3000) the "first" item?  Do you mean the first item per dataId?

Comment: Use .FirstOrDefault() after the Select

Comment: How would I loop through that result?  I'm getting an error in my subsequent foreach statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group your items by `dataId`, and then select first item from each group:

```
var myIds = (from a in myList
             where ListIds.Contains(a.dataId)
             group a by a.dataId into g
             let firstA = g.OrderBy(x => x.DataValue).First()
             select new {
                Id = firstA.Id,
                DataId = g.Key,
                DataValue = firstA.DataValue
             }).ToList();
```

Or with extension methods (it returns first item in original order):

```
var myIds = myList
        .Where(a => ListIds.Contains(a.dataId))
        .GroupBy(a => a.dataId)
        .Select(g => new 
        {
            Id = g.First().Id,
            DataId = g.Key,
            DataValue = g.First().DataValue
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: the extension method was clearer. This one is a pain to read :-)

Comment: @Aniket OK, I'll add previous version too :)

Comment: Thanks, that did it.  Will mark as answer when it lets me.  thanks for quick response.

Answer (score 1):

Use .FirstOrDefault() after the Select

```
 var myIds = myList
                .Where(a => ListIds.Contains(a.dataId))
                .Select(x=> new 
                {
                    Id = x.Id,
                    DataId = x.dataId,
                    DataValue = x.DataValue
                }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: thanks for this.  When I try to loop through the result my foreach statement errors.